# mysqldump - does it have non-repeatable DMLs?

Tags: mysql, restore, mysqldump

We are migrating databases using mysqldump, and since this is the first time I'm doing it, I have a couple of questions.

If in the middle of mysqldump the utility crashes(for some reason- latest was global max_allowed_packet error that I had to increase), can I just rerun the dumpfile completely or try to find how much it had progressed and start from there? Is the dumpfile from mysql

2nd question - I use 
    mysql -u <> -p<> < dump.sql 
method to restore. Any chance we can see how much it has progressed? Is there any utility that would allow me to see the progress since I'm restoring 2 TB databases ?

Comment: You do have a few TB of spare disk space??

Answer (score 0):

2TB restore from mysqldump?? How long do you have?

mysqldump  produces logical backup and it'd take longer to restore. Not scaring but I'd not dare to dump a 2TB database (unless you must)! I'd rather consider taking hotbackup.

About your other questions:

- mysqldump will generate simple D[MD]L queries... create table, insert, create triggers/routines etc..
- If mysqldump stops in between your dump will be incomplete, just like an incomplete SQL file!
- You  can always check mysqldump finished correctly by checking last line of the output file, should say something like "Dump complelted..."
- You may also check "$?" on shell  to confirm if the mysqldump command completed successfully.
- About your progress, mysql internally doesn't report progress but from linux shell you can use [(pipe viewer) pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/quickref/pv.shtml) command to know the progress.

Also:

- Do refer [mysqldump reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) from documentation.
- There existst [mysqldumpsplitter](https://github.com/kedarvj/mysqldumpsplitter) to split from large dumpfiles if required.
- If you consider to setup physical backup, [setup instructions for xtrabackup+holland framework](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/setup-and-configure-mysql-backup-using-holland-and-xtrabackup) are there too.